# Does science suggest Venus would resume plate tectonics if surface water were somehow reintroduced and rotation sped up?

Tags: geology, water

Assume that we're talking about a terraformed Venus with an Earth-like atmosphere so no risk of the water simply boiling away before being allowed to permeate the lithosphere.  Does this meet the sufficient criteria for plate tectonics, and would there be any factors may prevent it?

Comment: Wow, I wish this was even remotely answerable given existing scientific knowledge.  Worldbuilding SE contains numerous speculative answers about terraforming Venus.

Comment: I think this is answerable and the answer is yes, but possibly it would require a long time. The time scale of tectonical processes is ten millions of years, obviously such a change would not have any visible effects today.

Comment: Not sure what the point was in giving feedback and editing my question to make it more above board if you're just going to shut down my question as "opinion-based" (which isn't even remotely true). I mean, even the edit is stupidly pedantic. I'm pretty sure nobody reading my question is going to be fooled into thinking that employing a witch doctor or priest is the solution. Do we need to specifically refer to "science"? What other method is there to consider? voodoo? A seance?